# How to delete the whole li element containing selectbox using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to delete my dynamic selectbox if user choose to click on Delete (next to the selectbox). But I can't figure out how to impose the delete.

This is my code so far:

```
$(function() {
// set the array
var fruit = new Array("Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Banana");
var id = 0;

function addFruit() {
    $.each(fruit, function(key, value) {   
        $('#fruit')
        .append($('<option>', { value : key })
        .text(value)); 
    });
}

var i = $("li").size() + 1;
$("a#addmore").click(function() {
$("#addmore_row").append('<li>' +
'<select name="fruit[]" id="fruit_'+ id +'">' +
'<option value="">Select Fruit:</option>' +
'</select>' + '<a href="#" id="del_'+id+'">Delete Row</a>' +
'</li>');
addFruit();
id++;
return false;
});

});
```

Correct me if I am wrong, I think it's something like this. But I can't figure out what to put for [item]. Can please advise?

```
$([item]).click(function() {
$([item]).remove();
return false;
});
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: you want to delete the whole `select`?

Comment: for eg. if i have selectbox1, selectbox2, selectbox3, i would like to delete off the selectbox2 (inclusive of the whole li), by clicking on the Delete Row. How many I do it?

Comment: tomalak: added the id as unique id, modified the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sincle li has no id you can use traversing:

```
$('#del_'+id).click(function(event){
 $(this).parent().remove();
 event.preventDefault();
})
```

or add class to the remove link and just use:

```
$('.buttonToRemoveRowClass').click(function(event){
 $(this).parent().remove();
 event.preventDefault()
})
```

Comment: for some reason, this does not seems to be working properly. http://jsfiddle.net/cvCgb/

Comment: If updated your fiddle - moved my code to a place where id is still the same. plus added event.preventDefault()

Comment: Litek: Thanks it's working nicely. I see so it has to be within the section and not elsewhere. One more question, I don't really understand the need for the event.preventDefault(). Could you kindly explain what does it do within this snippet of code? Thanks.

Comment: Since you're clicking a link the default behavior it to take you to location specified in href attribute. event.preventDefault() prevents default behavior. You can try without it, and see that it reloads the page (since href="#").

Answer (score 1):

may not answer your question but by guessing your markup as

```
<li>
    <select>
        <option>as
        </option>
    </select>
    <a href="#">Delete Row</a>
</li>
```

you can try

```
$("a[href='#']:contains('Delete Row')").click(function(){

$(this).prev('select').remove();
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');

});
```

have  look here http://jsfiddle.net/nsJF5/

you can have a look [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to see how `prev` works.

Answer (score 0):

If your delete link is contained in the same dom element (i.e. a `div`) of the select you can traverse the dom by going up to this parent div an then finding the `select` to remove inside it. Sort of:

```
$("a.delete").click(function(){
  $(this).parents("div").find("select#fruit").remove();
});
```

If the delete link is a DOM successor of the select you can use `.prev()`:

```
$("a.delete").click(function(){
  $(this).prev("select#fruit").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to an element, you can remove it from the DOM using:

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

There's likely a shorter jQuery version if you want less typing.

Answer (score 0):

The parent element of the link is the li, so remove the parent when you click the link:

```
$("#addmore_row").append('<li>' +
  '<select name="fruit[]" id="fruit">' +
  '<option value="">Select Fruit:</option>' +
  '</select>' + '<a href="#" id="del_'+id+'"' + 
  'onclick="$(this).parent().remove(); return false;">Delete Row</a>' +
  '</li>');
```